# settings for iptables "recent" module

Tags: iptables, firewall

When using the `iptables` `recent` module, I can see the module settings here:

```
$ ls -1 /sys/module/xt_recent/parameters/
```

and list setting for particular parameter:

```
$ cat /sys/module/xt_recent/parameters/ip_list_tot
100
```

I also know I can change the defaults when loading the module.

My question is, what happens when the list reaches the size of `ip_list_tot`?

Does the `recent` module stop adding new IP addresses or does it "rotate" the old ones out and replacing them with new ones?

I looked in the help, but could not find any explanation

```
iptables -m recent --help
```

Also, what is a reasonable size for `ip_list_tot` in a production environment, where I want to block offending IPs? The default `ip_list_tot` size of 100 seems to me ridiculously small. Could I experience any negative effects if I set it to `10'000`?

Comment: Check if ipset (with timeout) can't be a replacement or an addition to recent. At least it has a forceadd to handle being full (and is meant to handle way more entries, like 100000+)

Comment: As a side note: iptables is deprecated so it might make sense to look at nftables instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading (very fast) the [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/netfilter/xt_recent.c#L178), I would say that the older entry is removed:

```
if (t->entries >= ip_list_tot) {
        e = list_entry(t->lru_list.next, struct recent_entry, lru_list);
        recent_entry_remove(t, e);
}
```

To increase this value, you can set the parameter while loading the module manually:

```
~$ sudo modinfo -p xt_recent
ip_list_tot:number of IPs to remember per list (uint)
ip_list_hash_size:size of hash table used to look up IPs (uint)
ip_list_perms:permissions on /proc/net/xt_recent/* files (uint)
ip_list_uid:default owner of /proc/net/xt_recent/* files (uint)
ip_list_gid:default owning group of /proc/net/xt_recent/* files (uint)
ip_pkt_list_tot:number of packets per IP address to remember (max. 255) (uint)
~$ sudo modprobe xt_recent ip_list_tot=10000
~$ sudo cat /sys/module/xt_recent/parameters/ip_list_tot
10000
```

Make sure the module isn't in use (disable firewall or, at least, rules that use the `recent` match) before unloading/loading.

To make this setting persistent, you can put a file under /etc/modprobe.d/xt_recent with the following content:

```
options xt_recent ip_list_tot=10000
```

(Note this method may not work and may be adapted depending on your distro).

Regarding the performance issues that may be met if you increase consequently this parameter value, it's quite hard to tell.
It depends on your hardware, on the other tasks running on the system, etc.

Still based on reading the source code and my own background on development, I would say that the main things you may be afraid of is the introduction of latency if, for example, the currently tested IP is the last one on the list **or** isn't in the list (which may occur frequently):

```
static struct recent_table *recent_table_lookup(struct recent_net *recent_net,
                        const char *name)
{
    struct recent_table *t;

    list_for_each_entry(t, &recent_net->tables, list)
        if (!strcmp(t->name, name))
            return t;
    return NULL;
}
```

Given `x` the complexity of `list_for_each_entry() + strcmp()`, the extra "cost" of setting `ip_list_tot̀  to a huge value is the time to browser the list.

Final complexity may vary between `1 * x` and `ip_list_tot * x`.

Nevertheless, I guess that chained list in kernel is well implemented, with performance and speed as a requirements.

To conclude, I would advice you to benchmark ... if possible.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any insights as to whether increasing `ip_list_tot size` to something much bigger than the default 100, would have any negative side effects ?

Comment: Answer edited !

Comment: thanks for the edit. But you did not adress the main question, whether increasing 'ip_list_tot size' to something much bigger than the default 100, would have any negative side effects. Is there a way to monitor CPU usage per module ? If I set this to one milion, can I see the performace hit zon my machine ?

Comment: Answer edited. It's quite hard to tell.... The only  way is, in my opinion, by testing.

Comment: @MartinVegter It looks pretty clear that they use a (linked) list of entries and since the search is linear so the time complexity is `O(N)`. A fast search would at least require a binary search: `O(log2(N))`. If you have 10,000 entries, it's going to check each one for regular clients (those not included in the list).